# Consider the PDE $3u_t + 6u^{10}u_x + u_{xxx} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE

$$3u_t + 6u^{10}u_x + u_{xxx} = 0$$

for the function $u = u(x, t)$.

(a)Let c be a constant and let u(x, t) = f (x − ct) be a travelling wave solution that satisfies

$$f(z), f′(z), f′′(z) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } z \rightarrow\pm\infty.$$

Show that $f$ satisfies the ODE
$$f′′ = 3cf − \frac{6}{11}f^{11}.$$

(b)Hence show that $f$ satisfies the ODE
$$(f′)^2 = 3cf^2 − \dfrac{1}{11} f^{12}.$$

At first I thought this problem was straightforward. My plan was to find partial derivative, sub into the pde then integrate to get part (a), and that works fine. However, when I integrate a second time I do not get the desired result. I must be missing something import.

**Attempt:**

We have the following partial derivatives
\begin{align*}
u_t&=-cf'(x-ct)\\
u_x&=f'(x-ct)\\
u_{xxx}&=f'''(x-ct)
\end{align*}
Let us now set $z=x-ct,$ and when we sub these into our pdf we get
$$-3cf'(z)+6f(z)^{10}f'(z)+f'''(z).$$
First integration gives
\begin{align}
\int -3cf'(z)+6f(z)^{10}f'(z)+f'''(z)\;dz&= -3cf(z)+\dfrac{6}{11}f(z)^{11}+f''(z)\\
&\Rightarrow f''(z)=3cf(z)-\dfrac{6}{11}f(z)^{11},
\end{align}
which ia the desired result. Now when I integrate a second time I get
\begin{align}
\int f''(z)\;dz &= \int 3cf(z)-\dfrac{6}{11}f(z)^{11}\;dz\\
&\Rightarrow f'(x) = \dfrac{3}{2}f(z)^2 - \dfrac{6}{132}f(z)^{12}
\end{align}
and multiplying through by a factor of 2 gives
$$2f'(z)= 3cf(z)^2-\dfrac{1}{11}f(z)^{12}.$$

which is close to, but defiantly not the desire result. I am hoping that someone is able to help me see where I went wrong with this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs when you integrate a second time.  Remember that you are integrating with respect to $z$, not $f$.  Thus, before integrating, you have to multiply by $f'(z)$ to obtain
$$f''(z)f'(z) = 3cf(z)f'(z) -\frac{6}{11}f(z)^{11}f'(z)$$
If you integrate this expression with respect to $z$ and multiply by $2$, you'll get the result the problem indicates.